# Filtering series with timedelta range

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have three datasets and all of them are timedelta64:

```
data1
1   17:49:43
2   09:44:37
3   10:45:52
4   12:58:31
5   16:09:18
6   14:42:53
7   16:19:24
8   15:13:03
9   13:56:40

data2
1   17:50:17
2   09:47:09
3   10:46:10
4   13:02:13
5   16:09:16
6   14:46:14
7   16:20:16
8   15:14:15
9   14:04:14

data3
1   00:00:34
2   00:02:32
3   00:00:18
4   00:03:42
5   23:59:58
6   00:03:21
7   00:00:52
8   00:01:12
9   00:07:34
```

I applied:

```
df_temp = data3['14:00:00' < data1 < '14:50:00'].mean()
```

Then, I got an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-234-1eb15c81506e> in <module>()
----> 1 df_temp = data3['14:00:00' < data1 < '14:50:00'].mean()

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
    951         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    952                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 953                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    954 
    955     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this issue is to convert to seconds and just compare integers:

```
x, y = pd.to_timedelta('14:00:00').seconds, pd.to_timedelta('14:50:00').seconds

df_temp = data3[data1.dt.seconds.between(x, y)].mean()
```